# Word macro delete spaces

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro to delete spaces between tables, which makes tables generated by a template file to join just by deleting space between them.

The issue now is it is also deleting footer in the word document.

here is my Code.

```
Sub AllignTables()

Dim oPara As Paragraph

For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.range.Paragraphs

        If Not oPara.range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then

            If Len(oPara.range) = 1 Then

                oPara.range.Style = "Normal"

                oPara.range.Delete

            End If

        End If

    Next oPara

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you

```
oPara In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory).Paragraphs
```